# C++ usage in embedded systems

Tags: c++, embedded

What features of C++ should be avoided in embedded systems?

Please classify the answer by reason such as:

- memory usage
- code size
- speed
- portability

EDIT: Lets' use an ARM7TDMI with 64k ram as a target to control the scope of the answers.

Comment: The document "[Information technology — Programming
languages, their environments and
system software interfaces — Technical
Report on C++ Performance](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c043351_ISO_IEC_TR_18015_2006(E).zip)" gives also some good informations about programming in C++ for an embedded device.

Comment: I wrote a small little "article" about embedded programming with C++ in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407003/where-to-find-information-on-embedded-c/3451301#3451301 I hope it can be useful for you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**RTTI and Exception Handling:**

- Increases code-size
- Decreases performance
- Can often be replaced by cheaper mechanisms or a better software-design.

**Templates:**

- be careful with them if code-size is an issue. If your target CPU has no or only a very tiny ínstruction cache it may reduce the performance as well. (templates tend to bloat code if used without care). Otoh clever meta-programming can decrease the code-size as well. There is no clear cut answer on his.

**Virtual functions and inheritance:**

- These are fine for me. I write almost all of my embedded code in C. That does not stop me from using function-pointer tables to mimic virtual functions. They never became a peformance problem.

Comment: It is not correct to state "templates always inline".  This is just wrong.  If you don't specify 'inline' on the declaration of the function  it will not be inlined.  The linker *should* remove duplicate instantiations.

Comment: I would still reject that templates are a problem here.  There is no "extra" cost in using a template vs writing two versions of the same code without a template.  Do you have an explicit example that would show where templates cause otherwise unnecessary bloat?

Comment: The bloat associated with templates has a lot to do with the tool chain and whether or not it can identify and consolidate multiple instantiations of the same type across modules. Many embedded tool chain do NOT consolidate. The other issue if unused methods in the template get optimized out or not.

Comment: Regarding duplicate instantiations.  As Avdi stated you should test your tool chain and then react, but you can also use explicit instantiations.

Comment: Regarding optimisation of template methods, well again, according to strict C++, if you don't use a method it shouldn't even be instantiated!  You can also enforce this using explicit instantiations.  I'll update my answer below with an example.

Comment: Richard, I'll update my answer with a little template-usage that bloats.

Comment: Richard, I'll made some more experiments and will change my answer.. :-)

Answer (score 14):

Choosing to avoid certain features should always be driven by quantitative analysis of the behavior of *your* software, on *your* hardware, with *your* chosen toolchain, under the constraints *your* domain entails.  There are a lot of conventional wisdom "don'ts" in C++ development which are based on superstition and ancient history rather than hard data.  Unfortunately, this often results in a lot of extra workaround code being written to avoid using features that someone, somewhere, had a problem with once upon a time.

Answer (score 11):

Exceptions are likely going to be the most common answer of what to avoid. Most implementations have a fairly large static memory cost, or a runtime memory cost. They also tend to make realtime guarantees harder.

Look [here](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/JSF-AV-rules.pdf) for a pretty good example of a coding standard written for embedded c++.

Comment: Probably way too old of an answer, but the link no longer works for me. Is there an updated link? I'm not 100% sure, but [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf) might be the same document

Answer (score 5):

It's an interesting read for the [Rationale](http://www.caravan.net/ec2plus/rationale.html) on the early [Embedded C++ standrard](http://www.caravan.net/ec2plus/index.html)

See this [article](http://www.embedded.com/97/feat9712.htm) on EC++ as well.

The Embedded C++ std was a proper subset of C++, i.e. it has no additions. The following language features were removed:

- Multiple inheritance
- Virtual base classes
- Run-time type information (typeid)
- New style casts (static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast and
  const_cast)
- The mutable type qualifier
- Namespaces
- Exceptions
- Templates

It's noted on the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C%2B%2B) that Bjarne Stroustrup says (of the EC++ std), "To the best of my knowledge EC++ is dead (2004), and if it isn't it ought to be."  Stroustrup goes on to recommend the [document](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/JSF-AV-rules.pdf) referenced by Prakash's answer.

Comment: EC++ mostly tried to solve the problems of C++ vendors, not progarmmers.

Answer (score 3):

Using an ARM7 and assuming you don't have an external MMU, dynamic memory allocation problems can be harder to debug.  I'd add "judicious use of new / delete / free / malloc" to the list of guidelines.

Comment: Also, dynamic memory allocation happens at runtime, whereas static memory is allocated by the linker. If it is possible to use mostly static data, this will be much faster (in one application I've been working on, I switched from dynamic to static and got a 50 % reduction in execution time).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using an ARM7TDMI, **avoid [unaligned memory accesses](http://www.arm.com/support/faqdev/1228.html) at all costs**.

The basic ARM7TDMI core does not have alignment checking, and will return rotated data when you do an unaligned read. Some implementations have additional circuitry for raising an `ABORT` exception, but if you don't have one of those implementations, finding bugs due to unaligned accesses is very painful.

Example:

```
const char x[] = "ARM7TDMI";
unsigned int y = *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int*>(&x[3]);
printf("%c%c%c%c\n", y, y>>8, y>>16, y>>24);
```

- On an x86/x64 CPU, this prints "7TDM".
- On a SPARC CPU, this dumps core with a bus error.
- On an ARM7TDMI CPU, this might print something like "7ARM" or "ITDM", assuming that the variable "x" is aligned on a 32-bit boundary (which depends on where "x" is located and what compiler options are in use, etc.) and you are using little-endian mode. It's undefined behavior, but it's pretty much guaranteed not to work the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

In most systems you do not want to use *new* / *delete* unless you have overridden them with your own implementation that pulls from your own managed heap. Yes, it'll be work but you are dealing with a memory constrained system.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have said there's a hard and fast rule to this; it depends a lot on your application. Embedded systems are typically:

- More constrained in the amount of memory they have available
- Often run on slower hardware
- Tend to be closer to hardware i.e. driving it in some way like fiddling with register settings.

Just like any other development though, you should balance all of the points you've mentioned against the requirements you were given / derived.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding code bloat, I think the culprit is much more likely to be *inline* than templates.

For example:

```
// foo.h
template <typename T> void foo () { /* some relatively large definition */ }

// b1.cc
#include "foo.h"
void b1 () { foo<int> (); }

// b2.cc
#include "foo.h"
void b2 () { foo<int> (); }

// b3.cc
#include "foo.h"
void b3 () { foo<int> (); }
```

The linker most likely will merge all the definitions of 'foo' into a single translation unit.  Therefore the size of 'foo' is no different to that of any other namespace function.

If your linker doesn't do this, then you can use an explicit instantiation to do that for you:

```
// foo.h
template <typename T> void foo ();

// foo.cc
#include "foo.h"
template <typename T> void foo () { /* some relatively large definition */ }
template void foo<int> ();        // Definition of 'foo<int>' only in this TU

// b1.cc
#include "foo.h"
void b1 () { foo<int> (); }

// b2.cc
#include "foo.h"
void b2 () { foo<int> (); }

// b3.cc
#include "foo.h"
void b3 () { foo<int> (); }
```

Now consider the following:

```
// foo.h
inline void foo () { /* some relatively large definition */ }

// b1.cc
#include "foo.h"
void b1 () { foo (); }

// b2.cc
#include "foo.h"
void b2 () { foo (); }

// b3.cc
#include "foo.h"
void b3 () { foo (); }
```

If the compiler decides to inline 'foo' for you then you will end up with 3 different copies of 'foo'.  No templates in sight!

**EDIT:**  From a comment above from  InSciTek Jeff

Using explicit instantiations for the functions that you know will be used only, you can also ensure that all unused functions are removed (which may actually reduce the code size compared with the non template case):

```
// a.h
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
  void f1(); // will be called 
  void f2(); // will be called 
  void f3(); // is never called
}


// a.cc
#include "a.h"

template <typename T>
void A<T>::f1 () { /* ... */ }

template <typename T>
void A<T>::f2 () { /* ... */ }

template <typename T>
void A<T>::f3 () { /* ... */ }

template void A<int>::f1 ();
template void A<int>::f2 ();
```

Unless your tool chain is completely broken, the above will generate code only for 'f1' and 'f2'.

Answer (score 1):

time functions are usually OS dependent (unless you rewrite them). Use your own functions (especially if you have a RTC)

templates are ok to use as long as you have enough space for code - othwerise don't use them

exceptions are not very portable also

printf functions that **don't** write to a buffer are not portable (you need to be somehow connected to the filesystem to write to a FILE* with printf). Use only sprintf, snprintf and str* functions (strcat, strlen) and of course their wide char corespondents (wcslen...).

If speed is the problem maybe you should use your own containers rather than STL (for example the std::map container to make sure a key is equal does **2 (yes 2)** comparisons with the 'less' operator ( a [less than] b == false && b [less than] a == false mean a == b ). 'less' is the only comparison parameter received by the std::map class (and not only). This can lead to some performance loss in critical routines.

templates, exceptions are increasing the code size (you can be sure of this). sometimes even performance is affected when having a larger code.

memory allocation functions probably need to be rewritten also because they are OS dependent in many ways (especially when dealing with thread safety memory allocation).

malloc uses the _end variable (declared usually in the linker script) to allocate memory but this is not thread safe in "unknown" environments.

sometimes you should use [Thumb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Thumb) rather than Arm mode. It can improve performance.

So for 64k memory I would say that C++ with some of its nice features (STL, exceptions etc) can be overkill. I would definitely choose C.

Answer (score 1):

Having used both the GCC ARM compiler and the ARM's own SDT I'd have the following comments:

- The ARM SDT produces tighter, faster
  code but is *very* expensive (>Eur5k
  per seat!). At my previous job we
  used this compiler and it was ok.
- The GCC ARM tools works very well
  though and it's what I use on my own
  projects (GBA/DS).
- Use 'thumb' mode as this reduces
  code size significantly. On 16 bit bus variants of the ARM (such as the GBA) there is also a speed advantage.
- 64k is seriously small for C++
  development. I'd use C & Assembler
  in that environment.

On such a small platform you'll have to be careful of stack usage. Avoid recursion, large automatic (local) data structures etc. Heap usage will also be an issue (new, malloc etc). C will give you more control of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a development environment targeted toward embedded development or a particular embedded system, it should have limited some of the options for you already.  Depending on the resource capabilities of your target, it will turn off some of the aforementioned items (RTTI, exceptions, etc.).  This is the easier route to go, rather than keeping in mind what will increase size or memory requirements (although, you should get to know that mentally anyway).

Answer (score 0):

For embedded systems, you'll predominately want to avoid things that have a definite abnormal runtime cost.  Some examples:  exceptions, and [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTTI) (to include [dynamic_cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast) and [typeid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid)).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you know what features are supported by the compiler for your embedded platform and also make sure you know the peculiarities of your platform.  For example the TI's CodeComposer compiler does not do automatic template instantiations.  As a result, if you want to use STL's sort, you need to instantiate five different things manually.  It also does not support streams.

Another example is that you may be using a DSP chip, which does not have hardware support for floating point operations.  That means every time you use a float or a double you pay the cost of a function call.

To summarize, know everything there is to know about your embedded platform and your compiler, and then you will know which features to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

One particular problem that surprised me with ATMega GCC 3.something: when I added a virtual ember function to one of my classes, I had to add a virtual destructor. At that point, the linker asked for operator delete(void *). I have no idea why that happens, and adding an empty definition for that operator slolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the cost of exceptions depends on your code. In one application I profiled (a relatively small one on ARM968), exception support added 2 % to execution time, and code size was increased by 9.5 KB. In this application, exceptions were thrown only in case something seriously bad happened -- i.e. never in practice -- which kept the execution time overhead very low.